# Why wont .html() work on class="error aTitle"

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the HTML of the following using jQuery

```
'<label for="aTitle" generated="true" class="error aTitle" style=""></label>';
```

But if I use the jQuery code below nothing changes. I cant remove the space there. Any other method that'll make this work?

```
$(".error aTitle").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
```

Comment: It is trying to match an element `aTitle`.

Comment: `error aTitle` isn't one class.  It's two classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the space and add `.` for class selector `aTitle`

```
$(".error.aTitle").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current selector `$(".error aTitle")` says to match all `<aTitle>` elements whose parent element has the CSS class `.error`, which isn't quite what you want.

To select the elements you want, you need to change your selector to `$('.error.aTitle')`.  Every class has to be preceeded by a period (to denote a CSS class), otherwise it'll be seen as an element (ie a `<div>`).  Spaces between items in a selector indicate heritage, so using a selector like `$('.error .aTitle')` means you want to select all elements with a CSS class of `.aTitle` whose parent element has the CSS class `.error`.

Another, further example of a selector you can use (which may be a bit of overkill) is `$('label.aTitle.error')`, which says to select all `<label>` with the CSS classes of `.aTitle` and `.error`.  This selector would not match, say, `<input type="text" class="error aTitle" />`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class="error aTitle"
```

You are actually setting **two** classes here, not one.  The element has the class `error` AND it has the class `aTitle`.

You want to select the element(s) that have both classes:

```
$('.error.aTitle')
```